# composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project

Tags: php, symfony4

While installing Symfony 4 with website-skeleton option i got this error. I'm using MacOs High Sierra and PHP 7.3.0beta3.
How can i solve this?

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for facebook/webdriver 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.6.0].
    - facebook/webdriver 1.6.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - facebook/webdriver 1.6.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - symfony/panther v0.2.0 requires facebook/webdriver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.6.0].
    - Installation request for symfony/panther v0.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/panther[v0.2.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/40-curl.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/40-openssl.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-apcu.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-curl.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-gmp.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-igbinary.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-imap.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mongodb.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mssql.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pgsql.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-propro.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-raphf.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-readline.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-redis.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xsl.ini
    - /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: As the error says _"requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing"_, you're missing the zip-extension for PHP. Install that and it should work.

Comment: Yeah but i didn't figure out how to do it on macOS

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing pearl following this tutorial
https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/

then i installed the zip extension by typing `sudo pecl install zip`